# Is the Legendre symbol with respect to a large prime usable as a pseudorandom generator?

Tags: number-theory, cryptography, legendre-symbol

Take an output length $\ell$ and a random seed $s \in \Bbb Z_p$ and a large 1000-bit or so prime number $p$ and output the Legendre symbols of $s, s+1, \dotsc, s + \ell - 1$ with respect to $p$.

There might be a vulnerability when $s$ is very close to $0$, so you need to give it a value sufficiently far away from $0$.

Is this a cryptographically secure pseudorandom generator? I can't seem to reduce it to any number theoretic problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"On the Randomness of Legendre and Jacobi Sequences", Ivan Damgård, CRYPTO 88.

"Quantum algorithms for some hidden shift problems", Wim van Dam et al., SODA '03.

"On finite pseudorandom binary sequences I: Measure of pseudorandomness, the Legendre symbol", Mauduit and Sárközy, Acta Arithmetica 1997.

From the van Dam article: "We conjecture that classically the shifted Legendre symbol is a pseudo-random function [...]"  They indicate Damgård says: "Given a part of the Legendre sequence (s|p), (s+1|p), ..., (s+l|p), where l is O(log p), predict the next value (s+l+1|p)" is a hard problem with applications in cryptography.